# How to integrate the Google Shopping Feed With Magento 2.4.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, google-product-feeds

How to integrate the Google Shopping Feed With Magento 2.4.3 ?

Content API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had to connect a Magento instance to Google Shopping last year and used the Magento module developed by Rocketweb for that: https://rocketweb.com/rocket-shopping-feeds

Worked good and their support was helpful in fixing a few minor issues we ran into.

Comment: Thanks, it works great